# Pygame Audio Stops When Window Switches?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I wrote a music player in Python using Pygame and Pydub(I used Pygame for actually playing the music, while Pydub is probably unrelated to the issue).

The music works fine even when windows are switched unless I switch to another Pygame window. I thought this effect would go away if I compiled it(cx_freeze), but that didn't work.

So I was wondering if there is any way to let the music keep playing when the window is switched to another Pygame window.

I used `pygame.mixer.music` instead of Sound objects if that might somehow be related.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you playing the same audio file in both pygame windows? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: There isn't even any audio in the other window. Also I just used `pygame.mixer.music.play`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a fix, but it seems that if I disable the mixer(`pygame.mixer.quit()`) it doesn't cancel out the audio. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use audio in two pygame windows at once.

Feel free to post another answer if anyone figures out a full fix.